# Grafana Loki pattern syntax error: unexpected IDENTIFIER

Tags: regex, grafana, grafana-loki

try to parse with pattern using **Grafana + Loki**

i am using

```
{pod=~"backend-deployment-.*"} |~ pattern `<_> - - <_> "<method> <path> <_>" <status> <_> "<_>" "<_>" <_> <duration> [<service>] [<_>] <_> <_> <_> <_> <_>`
```

to parse this log

```
10.110.1.132 - - [27/Aug/2021:02:37:06 +0000] "GET /main.d8e010115d6aba1bd049.js.map HTTP/2.0" 200 10842370 "https://gym.com/students/edit/173" "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_15_7) AppleWebKit/605.1.15 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/14.1.1 Safari/605.1.15" 34 20.031 [gymauto-gymauto-frontend-service-v1-8080] [] 10.110.5.217:8080 10842370 20.035 200 a7c4299aaa7ea674e91d13315
```

but there is error

```
parse error at line 1, col 35: syntax error: unexpected IDENTIFIER, expecting STRING
```

not like backtick , what is best solution i try " " also ' ' but same error. can not use pattern

Comment: Try this out on regex101.com to verify that the regex is doing what you want.  I'm also concerned about `[<service>]` because `[]` usually indicates a characters class, not sure that is what you want there.

Comment: I hit the same issue, seems to be a bug https://github.com/grafana/grafana/issues/54817

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to type it as "| pattern" instead of "|~ pattern"

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/32940764)

Answer (score 0):

Answer from @MCVL1911 is correct. you just need to remove redundant `~` before  pattern parser.
you can verify it using [LogQL Analyzer](https://grafana.com/docs/loki/latest/logql/analyzer/?query=%7C%20pattern%20%60%3C_%3E%20-%20-%20%3C_%3E%20%22%3Cmethod%3E%20%3Cpath%3E%20%3C_%3E%22%20%3Cstatus%3E%20%3C_%3E%20%22%3C_%3E%22%20%22%3C_%3E%22%20%3C_%3E%20%3Cduration%3E%20%5B%3Cservice%3E%5D%20%5B%3C_%3E%5D%20%3C_%3E%20%3C_%3E%20%3C_%3E%20%3C_%3E%20%3C_%3E%60%20%20&line%5B%5D=10.110.1.132%20-%20-%20%5B27%2FAug%2F2021%3A02%3A37%3A06%20%2B0000%5D%20%22GET%20%2Fmain.d8e010115d6aba1bd049.js.map%20HTTP%2F2.0%22%20200%2010842370%20%22https%3A%2F%2Fgym.com%2Fstudents%2Fedit%2F173%22%20%22Mozilla%2F5.0%20%28Macintosh%3B%20Intel%20Mac%20OS%20X%2010_15_7%29%20AppleWebKit%2F605.1.15%20%28KHTML%2C%20like%20Gecko%29%20Version%2F14.1.1%20Safari%2F605.1.15%22%2034%2020.031%20%5Bgymauto-gymauto-frontend-service-v1-8080%5D%20%5B%5D%2010.110.5.217%3A8080%2010842370%2020.035%20200%20a7c4299aaa7ea674e91d13315)

[image]